# Solving for x using inverse

Tags: discrete-mathematics, congruences

This last step makes me go crazy. I'll show you why:

I've got:

$\mathsf 15x \equiv 9 mod 27$

I see i can divide all three numbers by 3, so i proceed obtaining:

$\mathsf 5x \equiv 3 mod 9 $

With the Euclidean Algorithm i proceed to check that $\mathsf MCD(9,5) = 1$

And my inverse is $\mathsf e =2$

Multiplying both sides by  $\mathsf e$ gets me to:

$\mathsf 10x \equiv 6 mod 9 $

So i know the solutions have to be in the $\mathsf S= 6+9K$

Now, the solution is 3. I know that 3 is equal to 6-9. But why is it 3 and not 6? When i'm in this step, i really don't know which is the solutions, especially with big mods. I know it has to be x< mod, but i really don't know which one.

Same when i have

$\mathsf 2x \equiv 25mod7$

I do everything, and get to

$\mathsf 6x \equiv 75 mod 7$

75/7 gives me 5 as remainder. So i have

$\mathsf x \equiv 5 mod 7$

And know that the solution has to be $\mathsf 0 \le x < mod$ , but the solution is 2. 2 is equal to 5-7.

When do i have to subtract and when not to?

Comment: This seems wrong $x=6$ is a solution another solution is $-3$ and not $3$.Same as in the second $x=-2$ is the solution and not $x=2$.

Comment: Even if the signs are wrong, why do i have to subtract? And why is 3 the solution and not 6?

Comment: That's what I'm saying $6$ **is** a solution and $3$ **isn't** instead $-3$ is that's when you get $S=6+9K$ and plug $K=-1$.

Comment: $$x=6,15,24$$ are the solutions

Comment: (1) "Now, the solution is $3$." <-- How do you know that? It's not true, as your solution above shows. (2) "I know that $3$ is equal to $6-9$." <-- No, $3$ equals $9-6$, not $6-9$. Why are you subtracting backwards? (3) "When do i have to subtract and when not to? " <-- I don't understand the question. What do you have to subtract **what**?

Comment: $10 \equiv 1 \space (\mod 9) $ so just multiply your congruence equation by $2$ to get $x \equiv 6 \space (\mod 9)$. Now adding $9$ repeatedly will give you infinitely many solutions. Namely 6, 15, 24,...

Comment: Quoting:  "When do i have to subtract and when not to? " <-- I don't understand the question. What do you have to subtract what?'' response. When i'm doing congruencies (ax \equiv b (m) ) my b number will be greater than m. At lecture, someone told that if b is greater than m, you have to subtract until you dont get b<m. That's why i did it in the -3 case. I guess i shouldn't have listened to him. Though, i'll ask here hoping someone will clarify; when i got the inverse and i multiplied, what do i have to do? Do i have to divide b for the modulo and the remainder will be the answer?

Comment: $3$ isn't a solution - $15 \times 3 = 45 \equiv 18$ (mod $27$), which evidently isn't congruent to 9...